# gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view to show a listing of domestic sales and international sales. I share the same grid view for both. So if i select 'Domestic' radio button, i have to change the label of first column as 'SalesNo' and also set the sort expression as 'sales_No', if i select 'International' radio button, i have to change the label of first column as 'ExportNo' and also set the sort expression as 'export_No'. How can i do it using C# ?

Answer (score 0):

add gridview command radio buttons after adding radio button create gridview command event.
after all these things now any radio button selected check its value and after checking the value make changes as you want.